# Map to KML not exporting all layers within data frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml

I have about 12 layers in my TOC originating from various sources (Folder, GDB and another folder). I would like to convert all this to a KMZ file. When I select "Layers" in the "Map to KML" tool data frame I expect that all of them should export. However only a few of them do. And whats even more strange: they originate from different sources... one is GDB and the other is folder. I would like to know how I can get the Map to KML tool to export everything all at once.

Comment: Can you tell us more about those that export vs those that don't?  As a test can you Layer To KML those layers that do not appear to be working with Map TO KML?